# Validating Urls | Prepending http://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I want to check user submitted urls against a regular expression, if the url doesn't begin with http:// or https://, then I would like to prepend http:// to the beginning then save it.

I have some code but I don't know how to incorporate it into my app. Would this code work? And would I incorporate it into my application to check urls before allowing users to create links.

I've attached the code and files below. Thanks

```
def add_http(link)
  if (link =~ /http[s]?:\/\//)
    link
  else
    "http://#{link}"
  end
end
```

Controller https://gist.github.com/1279576

_form https://gist.github.com/1279580

Model https://gist.github.com/1279582

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add http(s) to URL if it's not there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908598/add-https-to-url-if-its-not-there)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed the code a bit. This works

```
  before_save do |link|
      link.url = "http://#{url}" unless link.url=~/^https?:\/\//
  end
```

Thanks for the guidance @bandito & @rubyprince

Comment: `before_create` will check the url only in the case of `creating` the record..u r better off using `before_save` which will be invoked before both `create` and `update`.

Answer (score 6):

You can place it in your model

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url
  before_save :sanitize_url

  private 
  def sanitize_url
    if url_changed?
     url = "http://#{url}" unless url =~ /^https?:\/\//
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. How would I apply the regular expression and conditional suffix to any url before saving it to the link table?

Answer (score 5):

The idea is fine. I'd write it like so, though:

```
def add_http uri
  uri =~ %r(https?://) ? uri : "http://#{uri}"
end
```

Much simpler, and no leaning toothpicks! :-D

Comment: Thanks, where to I put the code and how do I tie it into my app?

Comment: @bandito's answer answers that adequately. My answer was purely relating to the code style. :-)