# Ruby on Rails links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, href, actionview, sanitize

I have an instance with a description:

```
instance = Object.new
instance.description = '<a href=www.google.com >Google</a>'
```

Then in the view, I display it using

```
= sanitize(instance.description)
```

It displays the link correct but when I hover over the link and I look at the url it will redirect to ***'www.my-web-app.com/www.google.com'*** (it prepends the domain of my app to the correct url), anyone knows what's causing this? please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `http://` to the URL:

```
instance.description = '<a href=http://www.google.com >Google</a>'
```

Comment: i could do that but description will come from the app's user, and i have no control as what they will put in there, i guess i'll just have to look for all the '<a href>' in the text then make in '<a href='http://>' using gsub or something like that, thanks mischa

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908598/add-https-to-url-if-its-not-there

Comment: thanks. this looks promising as well, http://www.est1985.nl/design/2-design/96-linkify-urls-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2):

You `href` needs to have an http:// so,

```
instance.description = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>"
```

The problem is with the HTML, it has nothing to do with rails.