# Why alias_method fails in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, alias-method

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base

  #alias_method :name, :langEN # here fails
  #alias_method :name=, :langEN=

  #attr_accessible :name

  def name; langEN end # here works
end
```

In first call `alias_method` fails with:

```
NameError: undefined method `langEN' for class `Country'
```

I mean it fails when I do for example `Country.first`.

But in console I can call `Country.first.langEN` successfully, and see that second call also works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) (AFAIK via [`ActiveModel::AttributeMethods#method_missing`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-method_missing)) to create attribute accessor and mutator methods the first time they're called. That means that there is no `langEN` method when you call [`alias_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) and `alias_method :name, :langEN` fails with your "undefined method" error. Doing the aliasing explicitly:

```
def name
  langEN
end
```

works because the `langEN` method will be created (by `method_missing`) the first time you try to call it.

Rails offers [`alias_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute):

> **alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)**
>
> Allows you to make aliases for attributes, which includes getter, setter, and query methods.

which you can use instead:

```
alias_attribute :name, :langEN
```

The built-in `method_missing` will know about aliases registered with `alias_attribute` and will set up the appropriate aliases as needed.