# Rails: How to decorate an attribute in a similar fasion to alias_method_chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

In rails, this is a common pattern:

```
def foo_with_feature
  add_feature_to foo_without_feature
end

alias_method_chain :foo, :feature
```

I want to do this but with an attribute, whose getter method is not defined and will be done on-the-fly with `method_missing`, see [Why alias_method fails in Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727976/why-alias-method-fails-in-rails-model)

How can I decorate an attribute getter that hasn't been set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply access the attribute directly like so:

```
def fooattr_raw
  self.attributes["fooattr"]
end

def fooattr
  add_feature_to fooattr_raw
end
```