# How to display a youtube embed link that is called from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, youtube

I have an application I want to use for my teaching studio where I create lessons that students can view. the lessons are specific to each student so they are linked via a :user_id (user has_many lessons, lesson belongs_to user). I can bring up specific lessons based on which user it is but the one part I cannot figure out is how to get a video (youtube) link to display correctly.  What I want is to save the link  along with the text for the lesson.  The text and title and all that comes up fine right now, but the video will not display with embed code and throws a routing error in the iframe window.

Here is my code for the _lesson partial. "video_url" is the name of the column in the database.

_lesson.html.erb

```
<li>
  <span class="content"> 
    <%= lesson.title %><br />
    <%= lesson.lesson_notes %>
     <iframe width="490" height="275" src="<%= lesson.video_url %>" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </span>
</li>
```

this is the code in my show view.

show.html.erb

```
<% if @user.lessons.any? %>
 <h3> Lessons (<%= @user.lessons.count %>)</h3>
<ol class="lessons">
  <%= render @lessons %>
</ol>
  <%= will_paginate @lessons %>
<% end %>
```

the error I get is below

```
  No route matches [GET] "/users/www.youtube.com/embed/CFF0mV24WCY"
```

I kind of understand what is happening, but not really.  I guess I am unsure why it is looking for that route instead of just embedding the code and then displaying the video. It brings up all the other text and stuff from the lesson so that is working fine.  Is there not an easy way just to display the link so it embeds the video along with it?  I have searched quite a bit but everything I find just deals with embedding the code into the html which I can do, but this needs to change based on the user so has to be pulled out of the database along with the rest of the lesson info.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` needs to know the protocol, so if you don't include `http://`, the explorer assumes that the given `src` is next to your actual path.
A shitty solution could be add the protocol with a raw string:

```
src="http://<%= lesson.video_url %>"
```

But a way better solution is [adding a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908693/895789) to check if the protocol is included when you save the field.