# Convert url from https to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a url that uses https by default:

```
url = article_url(@article)
```

Instead of using https I would like the same url but using http

Comment: Do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908598/add-https-to-url-if-its-not-there

Comment: I hope you are searching for this piece of manual: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add http(s) to URL if it's not there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908598/add-https-to-url-if-its-not-there)

Comment: Quite a bit of research so far but worded the question in it's simplest form. I was looking for a protocol option as part of the rails url helper however the regex solution will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer I was searching for is:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

```
url_for(controller: 'articles', action: 'show', id: @article.id, protocol: :http)
```